# Is there a way to export to a CSV file by specifying rows in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

New coder here. I'm sort of aware how to export columns from a dataframe into a csv file but would like to know how to do the same sort of thing with rows. Below is an example of what I tried:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [7, 8, 9, 10]

dataSet = {"X": x, "Y": y}
df = DataFrame(dataSet, rows=["X", "Y"])
df.to_csv("rowstest.csv")
```

I would like the csv file to look like this:

X, 1, 2, 3, 4

Y, 7, 8, 9, 10

Is there a way I can do this?

I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) first and then not write default columns names in [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) by `header=False` parameter:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [7, 8, 9, 10]

dataSet = {"X": x, "Y": y}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataSet, orient='index')
print (df)
   0  1  2   3
X  1  2  3   4
Y  7  8  9  10

df.to_csv("rowstest.csv", header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataSet.T.to_csv(...)`

will transpose your columns to rows and rows to columns which i *think* gives you the output you want